# How do I change my "onchange" action in my "onchange" function

Tags: javascript, php, html, onchange

I'm making a table that only shows values biased on what is checked or not in my check-box. To change what is being showed in the table I've used an onchange. The function i cause it to use when it changes needs to be different for if the box is already checked or not.

Ex:

```
if(box is checked) {
   <input ... onchange=turnOnThisValue(thisvalue) ... >
}

else {
   <input... onchange=turnOffThisValue(thisvalue) ... >
}
```

The issue I've been having with this is that once I've unchecked a box, I need that input to now have the "turnOffThisValue" onchange function instead of the "turnOnThisValue"

The languages I'm working in are HTML, PHP, and my functions are in Javascript with the help of AJAX Calls

I would greatly appreciate any advice on this!

Comment: Instead, make a function `toggleThisValue` and have logic in that function that handles both cases.

Comment: Why not just make a new function `toggleThisValue` that checks the current value and flips it? Then you do not need to change the target of `onchange` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this? So it's just getting the element, and "onchange" is just a attribute you have to set.

```
document.getElementsById("idoftheinputfield").setAttribute("onchange", "turnOnThisValue(thisvalue)");
```